# add background color to all cell values of gridview which starts with upper letter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am newbie in ASP.NET and C#. I want to add background color to all cell values of gridview which starts with upper letter. Here is my source code:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[2];
                string entity = cell.Text.ToString();
                if (entity[0] >= 'A' && entity[0] <= 'Z')
                {
                  cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }  
            }
 }
```

But I got this error:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Source Error: 


Line 85:                 TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[1];
Line 86:                 string entity = cell.Text.ToString();
Line 87:                 if (entity[0] >= 'A' && entity[0] <= 'Z')
Line 88:                 {
Line 89:                   cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

Source File: c:\Users\Eric\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 87
```

Please help me to solve this error

Thank you to all

Comment: `char` has an `IsUpper` method. You could use `char.IsUpper(entity[0])`, just make sure that `entity` isn't null and has at least 1 character in it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
if (entity[0]...
```

If the value of the cell is null or empty, entity will not have any elements.  This will give you the out of range exception.

You can get around this by first checking if there are any elements in the array.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity) && entity[0] >= 'A' && entity[0] <= 'Z')
{
    //your code here
}
```

This way it will only check for the capital letter if a letter actually exists

Comment: You don't need brackets here: (entity[0] >= 'A' && entity[0] <= 'Z')

Comment: Your code it does not added to cells which starts with upper letter!

Comment: @mynhylisti the code you already had should do that.  I just provided a solution for the error you were getting.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.Text.ToString()` returns empty string like this: "". The problem is that in that cell you don't have any value, so when you try to access the first position in string, it throws that exception. At line 87, the exception message is pretty clear.

The solve is indeed to check for null or empty.